# Unable to read variable value from kettle.properties file

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have created a .ktr file which reads data from one DB and loads data to another DB. Environment is linux. If I run the .ktr file manually it works properly reading value of both source and destination DB from kettle.properties file. Now If i schedule .sh file in cron which should run automatically to load the required records. But that gets failed. I am assuming that its not able to pick the values when scheduled in cron from kettle.properties file. Do i need to restart anything on linux machine?

I get below error

Unable to parse URL jdbc:postgresql://${DEST_DB_IP}:${DEST_DB_PORT}/${DEST_DB_NAME}

But why this error comes? If i scheduled in cron and it works properly when i run the sh file manually.

Comment: Is read, write, and execute permission set correctly for the kettle.properties file? chmod